# "Locked Function" does not work anymore in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I had a working macro that correctly only made a few cells writable in a given workbook. However, after returning to the code 3 months later, the entire worksheet is locked, instead of the cells in question being writable, see code.

Is there maybe an update with Excel that prevents the correct locking of cells?

Thanks

```
Worksheets("XYZ").unProtect
Worksheets("XYZ").Cells.Locked = True

   Worksheets("XYZ").Range(Worksheets("XYZ").Cells(9, 4), Worksheets("XYZ").Cells(14, 7)).Locked = False

   Worksheets("XYZ").Protect
```

Comment: Try to place `Worksheets("XYZ").Protect` before the previous line

Comment: Move the protect command before the .unprotect one? I tried it and it doesnt work. Let me emphisize that the code worked before.

Comment: No, before the `.Locked = False` line. It would make more sense to me to first protect a sheet and then determine the cells that remain editable

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me on a test sheet. But I wonder if the sheet didn't unlock (password?) - as this will fail silently but then no changes will take effect. This version warns you if this happens

```
With Worksheets("xyz")
    .Unprotect  'must unprotect to make changes
     If .ProtectContents Then MsgBox "unprotect failed"
    .Cells.Locked = True  'lock everything
    .Range(.Cells(9, 4), .Cells(14, 7)).Locked = False  'unlock desired cells

    .Protect  'protect sheet, now the lock takes effect
End With
End Sub
```